# How to record data derived from COUNT DISTINCT query?

Tags: php, mysql, count, distinct, create-table

how to record data (into the database) derived from COUNT DISTINCT query? 
For example,

```
     Table1
       AA
       BB
       CC
       BB
       BB
```

Then the COUNT DISTINCT query outputs the following data 131 successively based on table1.
How to automatically create a table for 131 output?

Comment: just a temporary table that you can throw away later or a permanent one?

Comment: You wouldn't normally store derived data

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for [MySQL's `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-select.html):

```
create table mydistincttable as
select ... -- your actual query goes here
```

MySQL creates a new table with one column for each column returned by your query, (with equivalent datatypes) and fills it with the results of the query. The names of the columns of the created table follow those returned by the query.

As you would expect, that the created table has no indexes, constraints, or the-like - because such information cannot be inferred from a query. If you want such features, you need to add them manually after the table is created.

Answer (score 0):

that can be done with [mysql VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html)

```
CREATE VIEW view_name AS your_query ;
```